# Begin tikz path from other, morphed path

Tags: tikz-pgf, relative

I am drawing two concentric circles with arrows indicating shrinking. Ideally these arrows will all start on the edges of the two circles, not outside or inside as they currently do (see figure).
I do not know how to do this while simultaneously morphing the paths with random steps as shown.

How can I get the arrows to start from the morphed circles?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[fill=gray!75,even odd rule,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=0.2cm,amplitude=.1cm}] (0,0) circle (1.2)circle (.5) ++(0,-1.2);
   \foreach \n in {0,60,...,300}{
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)++(\n:0.5)--++(\n:.2);
    \draw[-stealth] (0,0)++(\n:1.2)--++(\n:-.2);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can also clip with the region and draw a rectangle and arrows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd draw the ring as two separate paths, one gray, one white, which could then be used with the `intersections` library. In order to get a properly closed path, I don't use the `random steps` decoration to draw the ring.

```
\documentclass[tikz,borde=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\draw [fill=gray!75, name path=A] (0:1.2)
\foreach \i [evaluate={\r=1.2+rand/10;}] in {10, 20,..., 350} { -- (\i:\r)}
  -- cycle;
\draw [fill=white, name path=B] (0:0.5)
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=0.5+rand/10;}] in {20, 40,..., 350} { -- (\i:\r)}
  -- cycle;
\foreach \i in {0,45,...,315}{
\path [name path=C](0:0) -- (\i:2);
\draw [->, name intersections={of=A and C}]
 (intersection-1) -- ++(\i+180:1/4);
 \draw [->, name intersections={of=B and C}]
 (intersection-1) -- ++(\i:1/4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly sneaky way around is to make the paths have a fixed radius where the arrows are 'emitted' and random every where else. Then the hole in the middle can be a proper hole:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\node [gray!20, scale=2] {Background};
\draw [fill=gray!75, even odd rule] (0:1.2)
\foreach \i [evaluate={\r=mod(\i, 45) ? 1.2+rand/20 : 1.2;}] in {5, 10,..., 355} { -- (\i:\r)}
  -- cycle  (0:0.5)
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\r=mod(\i, 45) ? 0.5+rand/25 : 0.5;}] in {7.5,15,..., 352.5} { -- (\i:\r)}
  -- cycle;
\foreach \i in {0,45,...,315}{
\draw [->] (\i:1.2) -- ++(\i+180:1/4);
\draw [->] (\i:0.5) -- ++(\i:1/4);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an OK workaround. It works for this scenario but I don't see it being very generalisable to other, arbitrary line decorations. The lack of transparency in the center is also a little unfortunate.

All that said this saved my poster, thank you very much, Mark :)

Comment: @Mr.V See the updated answer for a version with a proper whole. Still not generalizable to other shapes though.